# Issue with Advanced Image Recognition (AIR) Python BOT

Tags: python, winapi, keyboard, win32com, pyautogui

Having a weird issue with my Python Advanced Image Recognition (AIR) BOT, the BOT was originally designed to work with 2D websites like aimbooster.com, the purpose of the BOT is to target a specific color you give to it. My issue is that when I try to use it with 3D environments like a 3D Target Practice Shooter, the BOT detects the target color on the screen and shoots properly, but it doesn't shoot the color at all, if it detect the target color, all it does is shoot where  the user is facing, not actually shoot it's designated target. How can I fix this?

CODE BELOW:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

time.sleep(2)

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

#Color Of Center: (247, 10, 0)

while keyboard.is_pressed("q") == False:

    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(660,350,600,400))

    width, height = pic.size

    for x in range(0,width,5):
        for y in range(0,height,5):

            r,g,b= pic.getpixel((x,y))

            if b == 195:
                click(x+247,y+10)
                time.sleep(0.10)
                break
```

Comment: It's not clear how this code works. Your region starts at 660 and 350 (that's the offset) But you click a point with offset at 247 and 10.

Comment: *"How can I fix this?"* - The fix is to not assume that all programs observe message-based input. Games, in particular, generally detect input at a lower level (such as Raw Input). At any rate, this question (or a variation thereof) gets asked literally every day. The answer usually is: You're trying to solve a *really* hard problem. Python is very likely not part of the solution.