# How to send hardware keyboard or mouse press using any programming language?

Tags: winapi

I found a lot of answers about this question that works in notepad and other programs but doesn't work in a specific game!
it seems that the game block the inputs from my program.
here is the programs that I have tried.

1- using SendInput (c++)

```
#include <future>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::this_thread;
using namespace std;

UINT PressKeyScan(WORD scanCode)
{
    INPUT input[1] = { 0 };
    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[0].ki.wVk = NULL;
    input[0].ki.wScan = scanCode;
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE ;

    UINT ret = SendInput(1, input, sizeof(INPUT));

    return ret;
}

UINT ReleaseKeyScan(WORD scanCode)
{
    INPUT input[1] = { 0 };
    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[0].ki.wVk = NULL;
    input[0].ki.wScan = scanCode;
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;


    UINT ret = SendInput(1, input, sizeof(INPUT));

    return ret;
}
int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        PressKeyScan(0x39);
        sleep_for(milliseconds(100));
        ReleaseKeyScan(0x39);
        sleep_for(milliseconds(100));
    }
    
}
```

2- using SendKeys (C# winforms)

```
private void btnSendKeys_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iHandle = NativeWin32.FindWindow(null, txtTitle.Text);
    
    NativeWin32.SetForegroundWindow(iHandle);
    
    string keys = "";
    string space = " ";
    

    for (int i = 0; i < lbKeys.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (lbKeys.Items[i].Text.ToString() == "{SPACE}")
        {
            keys += space;
        }
        else
        {
            keys += lbKeys.Items[i].Text.ToString();
        }
    }

    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(keys);
    
}
```

both worked in notepad and some other apps but didn't worked in specific game.

Comment: Lots of dups if you search for *sending keystroke to games* E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138778/sending-keys-to-a-directx-game

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72958953/1889329) gets asked **literally** every day. Might want to do some research up front. The TL;DR is: Cheating is hard.

Comment: it's not working in crossfire game but works in other games

Answer (score -2):

I have tried to run the program as administrator and it finally works :D